# rails routing error: Controller required, when I am including controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

In my routes file:

```
 map.foo :controller => 'bar', :action => 'index'
```

I have a bar controller and I'm including it when adding this route, any idea why it throwing this error?

```
Illegal route: the :controller must be specified! (ArgumentError)
```

using rails 2.3.5

thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you stick with this old stuff? switch to ror3 as soon as possible!

Comment: we actually are in the process of switching, right now our app is using active scaffold too so we are looking into a different solution that is 3.0 ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify the URL you want to match.

```
map.foo '/foo/bar', :controller => 'bar', :action => 'index'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#named-routes

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the actual route:

```
 map.foo '/foo', :controller => 'bar', :action => 'index'
```